# Why can't my value pass through JSON to SHarepoint list?

Tags: metadata, ajax, json

With the follwing code, I am trying to update a list. Title succesfully passes but PerOrBus does not.

```
<script>
    $('#submitdata').click(function(){

    var itemProperties = {
        '__metadata': { "type": "SP.List" },
        Title: $("#firstName").val(),
        PerOrBus: "Yes"

    };



    $.ajax({
         url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ChangeOfAddressList')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data.d));
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data.responseText);
        }
    });
});


</script>
```

I get this error on the debugger:

```
"value":"The property 'PerOrBus' does not exist on type 'SP.List'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type."
```

Why would it update Title and not PerOrBus? PerOrBus is a checkbox so I've tried doing PerOrBus:"False" as well as making it true and null but none of them worked.
Any Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Try using 1 or 0

Comment: I tried that to no avail. However I think I need to declare it boolean somewhere maybe?

Comment: Are you sure that's the internal name? REST uses internal names, so if there was a space or it was renamed after creation, it could have a different internal name than the display name.

Comment: Hi Mike, That is the column name. Straight from /items url: <d:ContentTypeId>0x010000E29694B8D7EEF4EAEDAD5D400494DC</d:ContentTypeId><d:Title>c\s</d:Title><d:PerOrBus m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:PerOrBus><d:FirstName m:null="true" /><d:Surname m:null="true" /><d:BusName m:null="true" /><d:AccountsID m:null="true" /><d:coaCountry m:null="true" /><d:coaAddressL1 m:null="true" /><d:coaAddressl2 m:null="true" /><d:rmfj m:null="true"

Comment: thats a blank submission I got populating Title before I added PerOrBus to it

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Your metadata type is wrong. It should be SP.Data.ChangeOfAddressListListItem. The format is SP.Data.(list name)ListItem or SP.Data.(library name)Item when adding or updating an item.
2. You are missing some headers. A POST request signals an add but you want to do an update. To tell SharePoint that you really want to do an update you need to send the X-Http-Method header with a value of MERGE or PATCH. You should also send an IF-MATCH header to tell SharePoint how to do concurrency checking. I'm not sure if this header is optional or not. Finally, you should add a Content-Type header to tell SharePoint the schema of the message body.

Here is the code with these changes applied.

```
<script>
    $('#submitdata').click(function(){

    var itemProperties = {
        '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.ChangeOfAddressListListItem" },
        Title: $("#firstName").val(),
        PerOrBus: "Yes"

    };



    $.ajax({
         url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ChangeOfAddressList')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "IF-MATCH": "*",
            "X-Http-Method": "PATCH"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data.d));
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data.responseText);
        }
    });
});


</script>
```

Here's a working example from one of my conference talks:

```
function updateItem() {
    UpdateFormDigest(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl, _spFormDigestRefreshInterval)

    var call = jQuery.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Tasks')/Items/?$top=1",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });
    call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var items = data.d.results;
        if (items.length > 0) {
            var item = items[0];
            updateItem(item);
        }
    });
    call.fail(failHandler);

    function updateItem(item) {
        var call = jQuery.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
                "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Tasks')/Items(" +
                item.Id + ")",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "__metadata": { type: "SP.Data.TasksListItem" },
                Status: "In Progress",
                PercentComplete: 0.10
            }),
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "IF-MATCH": item.__metadata.etag,
                "X-Http-Method": "PATCH"
            }
        });
        call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var div = jQuery("#message");
            div.text("Item updated");
        });
        call.fail(failHandler);
    }
}
```

You can download the slide deck and the samples for the talk from http://ow.ly/4mRlUc

Comment: BTW, I cover this and more in my Client Object Model and REST API course on Pluralsight.

Comment: hi Rob, Thanks. I tried this and got the following on the chrome debugger: SP.ListItemEntityCollection does not support HTTP PATCH method."

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed that. You haven't specified which item you are updating. Your URL needs to be something like ".../getbytitle('ChangeOfAddressList')/items(" + itemId + ")"

Comment: I've added a second code example from one of my conference talks for you to reference.

Comment: So if I'm updating 5 items in one go I'd do something like 'ChangeOfAddressList')/items(" + FirstName + ")( " + Surname + ") etc? Your link is blocked on my network unfortunately

Comment: I've realized that I was confused there, Anyway I updated it with (" + id + ") however I am still getting the undefined error except now for id

Comment: Ah yes, because you only define ID when modifying an existing item. I want to create items